# Python/Tkinter - combobox get value from mysql

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm doing some tests with ComboBox and I was even successful, at first. I would like to know if I can pull the values ​​for the combobox from a mysql table.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root = Tk()

comboBox = ttk.Combobox(root,
                        values=[
                            '',
                            'test',
                            'test2',
                            'test3',
                            'test4',
                            'test5'
                        ])

comboBox.place(x=10, y=10, width=150)
comboBox.current(0)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Then this should help:

```
import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='some_username', password='password',
                               host='127.0.0.1',
                               database='some_database')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('select my_column from my_table;')
results = curs.fetchall()
curs.close()
conn.close()

results_for_combobox = [result[0] for result in results]

comboBox = ttk.Combobox(root,values=results_for_combobox])
```

Comment: It worked, but the values ​​came together  [link](http://prntscr.com/rj4172)